# how to set height to avoid white space in large screens

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design the following layout:

[image]

How do I set the height of each tile so that it scales in large screen monitors properly. I tried setting min height in px and height in %. But In large monitors there seems to be white space at bottom.

How do I make sure there is no white space at bottom in large screens while fitting perfectly in ordinary laptop display (mdpi) and also stacks one below another in mobile (I.e it is responsive). What units should I use.

Comment: Look up "flexbox".

Comment: Even in flexbox I do need to set height and min height don't I

Comment: try to use inline table and table cell. I often use this to align the height of div's.

Comment: I can't use table since it needs to be responsive

Comment: Could you provide example please

Comment: try to look at this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fzegy6gx/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is possible with `flexbox`es- you can see that it is clearly responsive.

I have created a viewport-high `flexbox` here. You can adjust the `height` of `wrapper` to get it as you have desired. See [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343852/how-can-i-achieve-this-css-layout-grid/39346086#39346086) for another example where the same thing is being done.

For showing how dynamic content behaves in this layout, have added some text content here with this css:

```
.content{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Check this out and let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper > div:last-child {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:last-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child > div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:last-child {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child > div:first-child > div {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }
  .wrapper > div:first-child,
  .wrapper > div:last-child {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .wrapper > div:first-child > div:first-child > div {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
          sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
          sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
        sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
      sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
    sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @kukkuz but now the elements are not stacking one below another in mobile layout

Comment: @user93 that was not specified in the question!

Comment: I guess you should use media queries to change the layout in mobile view...

Comment: is there another way without media queries. In general case while using floats when vw shrinks the divs which are unable to fit in one line will overflow to next line can such thing be done with flexbox

Comment: @user93 I have added some media queries for mobile view (say below 650px)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 flexbox will allow you to do this, quite easily. 
Here is a few links that will get you started:
https://envato.com/blog/css3-flexbox/

[Understanding CSS3 Flexbox](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/css-flexbox/)

Plus there are MANY other web pages on this subject. Google is your friend